# using Visual Basic for Applications to Click Button in Table

Tags: html, vba, dom

I am attempting to click a button that is present in a table.

```
<td class="b item enabled hasIcon" id="flowTile_2" 
   onmouseover="javascrpt:startHoverTimer(this);"
   onmouseout="javascript:startTimerToMaybeEndHoverMode(this);"
   onclick="javascript:runE1App('P4101','W4101E','DMS0001')" appId="P4101"
   formId="W4101E" version="DMS0001" tileText="Part Master" haveBox="true">
```

I've tried the following attempt:

I declare my variables properly as other clicking operations work properly elsewhere on the page.

```
            Set htmlDoc = .document
            Do While htmlDoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
            Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("flowTile_2")

                For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                        htmlInput.Click



                Next htmlInput
                MsgBox Counter
```

But I seem to get an object required error.

Comment: readyState loop should be the first thing in your code, before you try selecting any elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The table was inside of an Iframe that was referencing an outside URL, so I would not have likely been able to use it. The application permitted a paramterized URL system that took me directly to the page needed, at which point the code worked properly.